# Getting bad flag in substitute command '/' using sed replacement with custom string

Tags: bash, sed, escaping, special-characters, double-quotes

I'm using macOS Sierra, and I'm and trying to manipulate a value of a key from a config file.

In order to achieve that I'm using (which works fine for simple values):

```
sed -i .bak "/^$KEY/s/\(.[^=]*\)\([ \t]*=[ \t]*\)\(.[^=]*\)/\1\2$VALUE/" $CONFIG_FILE
```

Unfortunately, my string $VALUE is quite complex with many special characters, giving me the error:

> bad flag in substitute command: '/'

My $VALUE is being declared as:

```
VALUE='<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" ReturnPolicyIdList="false" CombinedDecision="false"> <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"> <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id"> <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">test </AttributeValue> </Attribute> </Attributes> <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"> <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"> <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">testing something</AttributeValue> </Attribute> </Attributes> </Request>'
```

Since I have double quotes being part of the value of $VALUE, I can't use double quotes instead of single quote when declaring it... Any ideas to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$VALUE` contains slashes which should be escaped because it conflicts with the separator for the substiture command

That's not convenient because if it changes, you have to escape them again. That's a solution, nevertheless.

Another simpler solution is to use an alternate separating character for s command which isn't in the `$VALUE` string, like `%` for instance (`%` has less chance to be in such a string, otherwise `|` can also be used).

```
sed -i .bak "/^$KEY/s%\(.[^=]*\)\([ \t]*=[ \t]*\)\(.[^=]*\)%\1\2$VALUE%" $CONFIG_FILE
```

or with pipe:

```
sed -i .bak "/^$KEY/s|\(.[^=]*\)\([ \t]*=[ \t]*\)\(.[^=]*\)|\1\2$VALUE|" $CONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: Works like a charm, anyway I would advice to use a different regular expression such as: "s|\($KEY[[:space:]]* *= *\).*|\1'$VALUE'|"